# Run the service until next schedule using Firebase job dispatcher

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I want to create a real time messaging app like whatsapp.
I have started it  with Firebase job dispatcher triggering every 60 seconds. But the issue here is it's not keeping the exact time. It's not at all working while phone is in idle.

How to keep the job service running until next schedule, and detect the new job request.

Answer (score 1):

Its behaving as expected. You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval.

During doze mode OS won't allow the Job-Dispacther to run. It will be only executed during maintanace window.  If your intention is to keep the Service alive, use ForegroundService and ensure you don't perform any CPU intensive work

Comment: But how whatsapp not showing notification, still alive to provide live message?

Comment: Whatsapp must have whitelisted itself. Refer this [document](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases) . Check the criteria for Whitelist [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases)